# Is it possible to declare class in if statement?

Tags: c++

So the problem is "Health" was not declared in this scope, I understand why and I think you understand what I want to do, I don't think it possible to do it with "if", is there another way?

thanks for your help

````
#include<iostream>

class Knight
{
    int health = 10;
};

class Mage
{
    int health = 8;
};


```
int main ()
{
    int player_class;
    std::cin >> player_class;

    if(player_class == 1) Knight player;
    if(player_class == 2) Mage player;

    std::cout << health;
}
````

Comment: Inherit the classes from a common base, then create `std::unique_ptr<Base>` outside of the if. `std::variant` could also work.

Comment: [Get a good book or two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282), read about inheritance and *polymorphism*.

Comment: They are declarations of variables, not classes. There are two class definitions in your code, but no class declarations.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can declare class object inside the `if-statement` but the scope of the declared object resides within the if-statement.

If you want at access it outside the `if-statement`, make a pointer and base class as follows,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>    

class base {
        public:
            int health;
            base(int arg):health(arg){ } 
   virtual ~base(){ }       
};

class Knight : public base
{
    public:
          Knight():base(10){}
};

class Mage : public base
{
    public:
          Mage():base(8){}
};

int main ()
{
    int player_class;
    std::cin >> player_class;
    
   std::unique_ptr<base>  bPtr;

    if(player_class == 1) bPtr = std::make_unique<Knight>();
    if(player_class == 2) bPtr = std::make_unique<Mage>();

    std::cout << bPtr->health;
}
```